# Which unit is better to use in css?

Tags: html, css

I'm using cordova and I have some absolute positioned elements that behave different depending on device resolution. Some text positioned over other elements if the screen is larger, for example.
What do you think is the best css unit to use for distances and position?
Do you have another approach to this kind of problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you need absolute positioning? It will be a nightmare trying to get the UI working properly for all the different types of displays!

Comment: I have many elements and there's one div which has to change position like in an animation.

Comment: I cant recommend using bootstrap enough

Comment: Could you post a jsFiddle with your problem and perhaps some code?

Comment: I agree with Dan Beaulieu... bootstrap, purecss' grid, or depending on your version of browser, flexbox.  Pure and bootstrap also have built in / easy to use media queries, so having your application display nicely on a range of screens is simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general I always use `rem` unless I specify sizes in percent of parent elements. This way you have a single reference for sizes, which helps me mentally relate one thing to another. Also, it all stays consistent when the user zooms.

If you need to make sure certain text has enough space or is abbreviated correctly, it's sometimes necessary to use JavaScript in order to resize based on available and needed space. A common technique is to render a simplified interface if showing on a small resolution. You can detect events like window resize, document load, etc.

If you need a more tailored answer, please make a jsfiddle to illustrate your problem.

Comment: pretty neat solution, I hadn't heard of rem before. Read for more details: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

Comment: I just want to point out that rem is a general unit for size, so not restricted to font-size

Answer (score -1):

Percent should do the job! It will scale according to the resolution.

Or maybe vm / vh is what you're looking for.

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units

Comment: I'm already using it but the problem is still there for some elements.

Comment: so is the problem because of scaling of the element itself? there is one solution where you put height:0 and padding-top:DESIRED_PROPORTION